# Django: предзаполнение формы редактирования пользователя

Tags: django

Есть модель User и модель Profile c полем OneToOneField к ней:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Ваше фото')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Фамилия и имя")
```

Так же вьюха для редактирования пользователем информации о себе:
**views.py**

```
def edit_trainer(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    profile = user.profile
    form = ModelProfileForm(instance=user)

    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.id == user.id:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ModelProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)

            if form.is_valid():
                update = form.save(commit=False)               
                update.user = user
                update.save()
                message = form.cleaned_data['name']
                recipients = ['email@gmail.com']
                subject = "Тренер отредактирован"
                email = 'email@gmail.com'
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, email, recipients)
            except BadHeaderError: #Защита от уязвимости
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found')
            return HttpResponse('Профиль успешно отредактирован') 
    else:
        form = ModelProfileForm()
    return render(request, "profile/edittrainer.html", {'form': form})
```

Все работает, но не знаю как передать предзаполненные значения форм из БД, чтобы пользователь мог видеть свои текущие настройки. Пробовал во вьюхе вставлять

```
form = ModelProfileForm(instance=user, initial=profile)
```

Но это вызывает ошибку

```
'Profile' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Добавил. Я так понимаю ожидается словарь, а приходит что то другое

Comment: Если `ModelProfileForm` - это модельная форма, то вместо `initial` надо использовать [instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values), а если нет, то передавать словарь, в котором ключами служат имена полей.

Comment: Никак. В модельной форме должны быть поля используемой ею модели.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось. Заменил instance=user на instance=profile